# Can a hot PCI adapter slow down the computer?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature, pci

Using the "watch sensors" command in Fedora, I see that while the temperature of the CPU's are normal (70 degrees at most), the PCI easily exceeds 90 degrees (celcius, of course.) Once the PCI gets hot, the computer slows down drastically. Is there possibly a connection, and if yes, is there a way to solve it? Do I simply have to check for dust etc?

Comment: What was in the PCI slot?

Comment: Result of lspci in Fedora: http://imgur.com/pM2hVJN

Comment: I do note that the problem is *less* present when having the charger plugged in.

Comment: something is horrible wrong the only device that runs 90c normally is a radeon 290x, but that is PCI-E.  Either use an air compressor or buy a can of compressed air to blow out the dust.

Comment: If that fails find out how to open it and clean it out.  Some laptops have had bad thermal paste that hardens and becomes useless.  Maybe you GPU needs new thermal paste.